# How to marshal .NET string to variant for COM call

Tags: c#, com, interop, marshalling, variant

I'm using a third-party COM library from C#.

There are get/set methods that take a parameter of type VARIANT (type VT_BSTR).
In the .NET wrapper, these parameters appear as type `object`, i.e.

```
object getValue();
void setValue( object val );
```

The getValue method works ok, I perform a simple cast of the object to type string:

```
string str = (string)comObject.getValue();
```

but setting the string in a similar way doesn't:

```
string str = "test";
comObject.setValue( str );
```

The third party library doesn't like this and generates an exception. It must be expecting a VARIANT of type VT_BSTR (as this works from native C++). So my question is, how do I create one of these in C#?

I've been looking at methods like `Marshal.GetNativeVariantForObject`, but documentation on correct usage of this seems a bit thin on the ground, so any example code would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`BStrWrapper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.bstrwrapper.aspx) class:

```
comObject.setValue(new BStrWrapper(str));
```